# Zoom out fractals? (A question about selfsimilarity)

Tags: terminology, fractals, complex-dynamics

It is well known that if we zoom in on the Mandelbrot set we get selfsimilarity.
So I wonder if $g$ is a fractal (in the complex plane) generated by a nonperiodic nonpolynomial entire function $f$

$g:=  f(f(...))$

Is it possible that the fractal is infinite in size and that when we zoom out , we get selfsimilarity too ? Lets call such a fractal a " zoom out fractal ".

---

As example Mandelbrot : $f(z)=z^2+1$, g$(z) [= f(f(...))]$ is the fractal.
The fractal has finite size (area or length ) since it diverges for $Re(z)>2$.
$f(z)$ is a nonperiodic nonpolynomial entire function. But when we zoom out we get no selfsimilarity. ( divergence is not considered valid as selfsimilar ) So Mandelbrot is NOT a zoom out fractal.

---

Does the existance of zoom out fractals require that the fractal is also a zoom in fractal ?

What is the formal way or term to express ' zoom out selfsimilarity ' or ' zoom out fractal ' , if any ?

Comment: How do you mean this $g=f(f(\dots))$?

Comment: @Berci : Well let $f$ be $z^2 + 1$ , then you get the Mandelbrot.
I think that example is clear.

Comment: The Newton fractal probably fits the bill: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling#Aperiodic_hierarchical_tilings

Comment: No guys , Newton fractal is not an iteration of an entire function $f$ like mandelbrot's $f = z^2 + 1$.
Also some tiling is not an entire function $f$.

Comment: I edited the question. I think it is more clear now.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300603/do-there-exist-periodic-fractals-a-f-of-this-type

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A serious candidate for $f(z)$ is the following function : $\displaystyle f(z)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_\epsilon^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{zt}}{t^t} \, dt $.

The reason is that the entire function $f(z)$ is bounded for $\mathrm{Im}(z)^2 > \pi$

This was given here : [Entire function $f(z)$ bounded for $\mathrm{Re}(z)^2 > 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616393/entire-function-fz-bounded-for-mathrmrez2-1)

See also : [How fast does the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_\epsilon^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{xt}}{t^t} \, dt $ grow?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619963/how-fast-does-the-function-displaystyle-fx-lim-epsilon-to0-int-epsilon)

It would be nice to see a plot.