# Entire function $f(z)$ bounded for $\mathrm{Re}(z)^2 > 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z$ be a complex number and $\mathrm{Re}$ denote the real part.

Does there exist a nonconstant entire function $f(z)$ such that $f(z)$ is bounded for  $\mathrm{Re}(z)^2 > 1$ ?

Comment: you mean for $|x| > 1 , z = x + iy$ ?

Comment: @arbautjc Please make that an answer, since it clearly is.

Comment: @arbautjc It's to get it off the unanswered list.  Copy paste of the comment would *be* an honest answer.

Comment: @WimC Ok, done :-)

Comment: I remark that there is an elementary answer to this as well. I mean there is an elementary function $f(z)$. I will get back to that later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the function f defined in section 12.2 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=MKPe1Q9k-nAC&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164), in Complex Analysis by Joseph Bak and Donald J. Newman.

It defines an entire function $f$ bounded outside the strip $|\mathrm{Im}(z)|\leq \pi$, and by a suitable linear transformation, namely $\theta(z)=i\pi z$, it's possible to get the function you want, $f\circ \theta$.

$$f(z)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{zt}}{t^t}\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Could you transcibe the definition here? The page doesn't display on google books.

Comment: Can you prove the boundedness of $f(z)$ ? Merry X-mas !!

Comment: Thank you arbautjc , Joseph Bak and Donald J. Newman !!

Answer (score 3):

A more general statement follows from an approximation theorem due to [Alice Roth](https://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/aliceroth.htm), which can be found in the book [Lectures on Complex Approximation](https://books.google.com/books?id=20RvBgAAQBAJ) by Dieter Gaier.

> **Theorem**. Suppose $F\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a closed set such that its complement is connected and locally connected at $\infty$. Let $f$ be a function that is holomorphic on an open subset containing $F$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an entire function $g$ such that 
>   $$|f(z)-g(z)| < \min(\epsilon, |z|^{-1}),\quad z\in F$$

For example, letting  $F=\{z: |\operatorname{Re} z|\ge 1\}$ and $f(z)=1/z$ yields a nonconstant entire function that is bounded on $F$ (and also tends to zero away from a horizontal strip).

But one can go further and let, for example, $F=\{x+iy: |y|\ge \exp(-x^2)\}$; that is, the infinite strip can be narrowing at infinity, with any rate one wishes.

Comment: so for any path to $\infty$ there is an entire function unbounded only in the neighborhood of that path ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.