# An entire function bounded outside a strip which contains the reals is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, laurent-series

Let $f$ be an entire function, which takes real values on the real axis and has no zeros. Suppose $f$ is bounded for $|\operatorname{Im} z| > a > 0$ where $a>0$. Is $f$ a constant?

---

I would be able to conclude this with Liouville's theorem if I knew that $\operatorname{Im}z$ is bounded in the strip $|\operatorname{Im} z|\le a$, but I don't see how to prove this.

Comment: Show that $f$ is bounded on the strip $|\text{Im} z| \le a$ too, so it's bounded everywhere, then apply Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Thanks Alex M. for your answer. The problem is precisely that we can not show that the function is bounded for |Im z|<a.

Comment: entire functions are constructed by : starting from polynomials, constructing new functions by addition and multiplication and also converging infinite sums and products (which allows $f \to e^f$) thus  if you can prove the theorem for polynomials and by induction following each of these construction rules, you'll get your theorem. another way would be to find a trick (like applying the the maximum or minimum modulus to $\cos(f)$) directly showing that the function has to be constant, but it will be a less general approach

Comment: i am sure this is a duplicate q.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entire function $f(z)$ bounded for $\mathrm{Re}(z)^2 >1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616393/entire-function-fz-bounded-for-mathrmrez2-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616393/entire-function-fz-bounded-for-mathrmrez2-1/616717#616717) and in [that book p.153-155](http://www.targetpointcms.com/Complex%20Analysis%20(Text%20Book)%20Final%20Year.pdf) that this would be a counter-example :

$$f(z) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{z t}}{t^t}dt$$

which is an entire function bounded by $ \frac{1}{|c|}$ on any ray starting from the origin to infinity with an angle $\pm e^{i (\pi/2 \pm c)}$. Thus it is unbounded only on a small strip around the imaginary axis.

(I'm not 100% convinced of his  proof yet)

Comment: The present question requires also that the function have no zeros.  But $\exp f(z)$ seems to do the trick.