# for $abs(Re(z))>\frac{1}{3}$ : $ Sign( Re(f(a+bi))) = Sign( Re(a)) $?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, examples-counterexamples, special-functions

Let $\operatorname{abs}$ denote the absolute value (of a complex number) and $\operatorname{sgn}$ the signum function. Also $\operatorname{Re}$ means the real part of a complex number.

Im looking for real-entire functions $f(z)$ such that for $\operatorname{abs}(\operatorname{Re}(z))>\frac{1}{3}$ and $z = a + bi$:

$$ 
\operatorname{sgn}( \operatorname{Re}(f(a+bi))) = \operatorname{sgn}(a) 
$$

or stated differently:

$$ f(a + bi) = g + h i $$
$$ 0 < ga $$

I was inspired by $\operatorname{Si}(z)$.

I also wondered how fast these functions can grow in the direction of positive or negative infinity.

Ps: for those unaware : A real-entire functions is a function that is entire(analytic on the entire complex plane) and maps all reals to reals.

Comment: @vitamind  thanks

Comment: At the end you are trying to find functions that depend on the signum function is the last step, so you're only checking if $1=1$ or $1≠1$ etc. It's seems clear to me that these functions f do not have anything more specific in common.

Comment: sign(-7) = -1 sign(-0.1) = -1 sign (2) = 1. 
Are you talking about the same sgn function ?
If so , I am unclear what you meant.
@vitamind

Comment: the trivial solution $a z + b$ for $a,b$ positive reals is ofcourse known.
Possibly related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616393/entire-function-fz-bounded-for-mathrmrez2-1?rq=1

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function. Also the question about growth "I also wondered how fast these functions can grow in the direction of positive or negative infinity" doesn't make sense.

Comment: that question does make sense , the lineair solution $az + b$ grows linear in the direction of positive or negative infinity. $Si$ grows towards constants etc

Comment: Do you agree with me that there are infinitely many linear, quadratic, cubic... functions that can satisfy the conditions you stated?

Comment: I dont know. z^5 does not satisfy it.

Comment: What do you mean by ”real-entire” functions? Are you perhaps interested in analytic functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that the real part is an even function?

Comment: A real-entire functions is a function that is entire and maps all reals to reals.

Comment: @mick What do you mean by "Im looking for real-entire functions"? (real-entire is called (real)-analytic) What answer do you expect? Examples or a class functions for example "linear functions" or...?

Comment: wait real-analytic implies analytic near the real line. It could have a pole at $i$. So that is not the same.
@vitamind

Comment: @mick That's why real analytic $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. But please answer my other question.

Comment: How do you mean " what do you expect " ? I ask for a function with properties so I want a function with those properties. Or many of them.